# Por que no me muestra el resultado de la busqueda con Django?

Tags: python, django, buscador, django-views

no me muestra el resultado de la busqueda (lo busca por el url pero no me muestra el post que filtra por un metodo GET Y me da un resultado de del base.html pero sin el post que estoy buscando) no se si tendria que en el template_name pasarle el template list donde listo todos los posts

me ayudarian un monto si pudieran ayudarme a resolver esto...Gracias!!!

Este seria el codigo completo de views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from posts.models import Post, Comment, PostView, Like
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = self.get_object()
            comment = form.instance
            comment.user = self.request.user
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect("detail", slug=post.slug)
        return redirect("detail", slug=self.get_object().slug)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'form': CommentForm()
        })
        return context


    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        object = super().get_object(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            PostView.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user, post=object)
        return object

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'view_type': 'create'
        })
        return context

class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'view_type': 'update'
        })
        return context


class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

def like(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    like_qs = Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post)
    if like_qs.exists():
        like_qs[0].delete()
        return redirect('detail', slug=slug)
    Like.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
    return redirect('detail', slug=slug)
    

def Search(request):
    template_name = "posts/post_list.html"
    buscador = request.GET['buscador']
    posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=buscador)
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Funcion de barra de busqueda

```
def Search(request):
    template_name = "base.html"
    buscador = request.GET['buscador']
    posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=buscador)
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

y tambien probe en este caso cambiar la direccion del template_name

```
def Search(request):
    template_name = "posts/post_list.html"
    buscador = request.GET['buscador']
    posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=buscador)
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Este seria el codigo de urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from posts.views import (
    PostCreateView,
    PostListView,
    PostDeleteView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostUpdateView,
    like,
    Search,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('search/', Search, name='search'),
    path('create/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('<slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('<slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    path('like/<slug>/', like, name='like'),         
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static (settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Este seria el codigo de post_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for object in object_list  %}
        <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="{{ object.thumbnail.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">    
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{object.title}}</h5>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ object.content|truncatechars:40 }}</p>
                        <hr/>
                        <p>
                            <a class="text-muted" href="{{ object.get_like_url }}"><span><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up ml-2"></i>{{ object.get_like_count }}</span><a>
                            <span><i class="fas fa-message ml-2"></i>{{ object.get_comment_count }}</span>
                            <span><i class="fas fa-eye ml-2"></i>{{ object.get_view_count }}</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="cardd-text">
                            Posted {{ object.publish_date|timesince }} ago
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Este seria  el codigo de  base.html de donde heredan las demas templates
aqui es donde tengo mi barra de busqueda (Search)

```
<form class="d-flex" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="GET">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search" name="buscador">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: No pegues imágenes del código, insértalo directamente en la pregunta usando el bloque de código. Ya que de esta manera como lo compartes se hace imposible copiarlo para poder reproducir el error en caso de ser necesario.

Comment: @KevinRamirezZavalza ok muchisimas gracias por el consejo ya borre las imagenes

Comment: Gracias, si pudieras compartir también tus urls.py y tu template donde muestras los resultados de tu busqueda.

Comment: @KevinRamirezZavalza Gracias a ti por los consejos... ya comparti el codigo de urls.py y el de post_list.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo modificaría el método `get_queryset` de la vista `PostListView` y quedaría mas compacto el código, sin necesidad de crear una FBV, ni una url aparte para acceder a un resultado que puedo filtrar en otra vista. En caso de que quiera personaliza el nombre de tu objeto en el contexto lo puedes hacer y el tambien puede agregar la ruta del template si así lo requieres.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = "posts/post_list.html"
    
    def get_queryset(self)
        buscador = self.request.GET['buscador']
        return super().get_queryset().filter(title__icontains=buscador)
```

Comment: Gracias Justo eso hice... Gracias por los consejos

Answer (score 1):

Creo el problema se encuentra en tu post_list.html

Te explico por que, en tu view Search, estas pasando los resultados al key del contexto 'posts', también ahí podrías ver si te esta llegando el termino de búsqueda con un print.

```
def Search(request):
    template_name = "posts/post_list.html"
    buscador = request.GET['buscador']
    print('termino de busqueda', buscador)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=buscador)
    print('resultados', posts)
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Y en tu post_list.html estas usando object_list en lugar de posts, iría así:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">    
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ post.content|truncatechars:40 }}</p>
                        <hr/>
                        <p>
                            <a class="text-muted" href="{{ post.get_like_url }}"><span><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up ml-2"></i>{{ post.get_like_count }}</span><a>
                            <span><i class="fas fa-message ml-2"></i>{{ post.get_comment_count }}</span>
                            <span><i class="fas fa-eye ml-2"></i>{{ post.get_view_count }}</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="carddtext">
                            Posted {{ post.publish_date|timesince }} ago
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```